# Exclude input from post array

Tags: php, drupal, post

In a form(in Drupal) I want to have a temporary field that there is no need to save it's value  in database. So I need a way to prevent form from sending the field's value to $_POST array. Is it possible?

Comment: does it need to be editable? if not, you can disable the input and it won't be send

Comment: What is the purpose of this field? The value will be discarded, so why do you need it at all?

Comment: @MrLister: It's a drop down list that when user selects an option, another text field will be filled by drop down's value

Comment: Oh, and the other field will be editable? OK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- If it's outside the form being submitted, it won't be sent by the browser.
- If it doesn't have a `name`, it won't be sent by the browser.
- If it is disabled, it won't be sent by the browser.

See [Form submission: Successful controls](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2) for the complete rules.

That said, your approach is very very wrong. You shouldn't decide what to put in a database based on what comes from the client. The client can send you anything!

Comment: Your answer is fine but the remark about not using client data to update the database is quite confusing.  How else are you suppose to know what the client wants to update?

Comment: @Cerad, this is obviously something the OP wants to control, and he's doing it by asking an untrusted 3rd party to do the right thing. That's a recipe for disaster.

Answer (score 1):

Just don't give it the `name=""` attribute.

You can also exclude it from the `$_POST` array when placing it in the database